# How to make Hudson promote a build after the completion of chained downstream jobs?

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I'm using the Hudson promoted build plugin to try an automatic deploy if all of the maven projects are good.

My setup is similar to the following

Hudson job creates a version control tag and then triggers downstream builds of projects A and B.  A triggers a downstream project Z.

I currently have the promoted builds plugin listening for success of A,B,Z.  But no promotion ever happens.

I currently don't have the project triggering all 3 since there is no point in building Z before A.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work if you listen only for the success of B and Z?

Comment: No and it also doesn't work if I just directly build Z and it passes.  Maybe time to file a hudson bug report.  Hudson version 1.342, promoted-build-plugin version 1.6

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to configure fingerprinting so that Jenkins can keep track of which downstream build tested which upstream build.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the **[Build Pipeline Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin)**, or take some inspiration from Kohsuke's recent blog post **["Doing choreography/workflow with Jenkins CLI"](https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/entries/477213-doing-choreography-workflow-with-jenkins-cli)** (login with CloudBees/Google/GitHub account required) which should give you more freedom in orchestrating your jobs.